# Reverse Diode and Resistor in parallel for battery connection. What do they do?

Tags: power-supply, batteries, diodes

Can you please help me understand what the diode and resistor connected to the battery input line of this circuit are doing? Thank you!

[image]

Comment: It's a bad reset circuit. Use this if you hate your users and want to save a few pennies.

Answer (score 2):

This is called a power-on reset. When power first comes on, charge flows through R14 to slowly charge C5. While this is going on, whatever is connected to the HARD-RESET line will be held in reset until the voltage passes the threshold from logical '0' to '1'.

When power is cut off, D1 quickly drains C5 so that the reset line functions correctly for any subsequent power-on.

You want a power-on reset so that everything gets set to a known state when you first apply power.

Answer (score 0):

Hard reset (base of transistor) pulls C5 low, and C5 voltage slowly increases (time constant is 100 mSec) as the capacitor charges.  Diode discharges C5 fast if battery input is grounded, so you get a delay during start-up after a power dropout.

Answer (score 0):

For a given DC supply the voltage rise with power one in less than say T.on and decays from AC shutoff or failure in T.off.

THe criteria for a good Power On Reset , POR design allows the design to function when the DC voltage is good and RESET when it is not OK such that a Low Reset is applied for a minimum required for the uC or circuit reset.

Ideally, you use some DC comparator to detect DC = OK  ( determined by IC specs and operating frequency ) like Vdd min spec at x MHz.

Then you choose an RC time constant to meet the minimum criteria of the design to ensure Reset by State duration = low when power is OK and stable so that it can perform the initialization.  Normally there is some hysteresis between going "Not OK" and OK of say 10% below threshold unless you need some early warning while the DC decays to have an orderly shutdown or fail safe condition on peripherals or I/O's or send some emergency message, going down? to a remote link.

### Answer

All this circuit does is dump the Cap charge to 0.7V or whatever the diode drop is during a power interruption and allow  a slow rise time of 100k * 1uF = ~ 0.1 s to reach 64% of Vdd which my that time it ought to be a Logic 1 and out of Reset and moving towards 90% or some level of power OK maybe or not.

So that's all the D1//R14 does and it knows nothing about your T.off fall time nor T.on rise time but expects that it is much much faster but may not react to a negative reactive glitch or sudden drop  on the power rail, or any other unforeseen DC "not OK" situation.

As @Spehro meant, the design is not done very well, but can work in some situations if you don't care about worst case or your friends that might use it.

There are many simple cheap & dirty POR designs but one needs to know the quality of the supply and T1, T2 and any load noise issues but the better ones detect DC OK then keep Reset low for the required min. time.